# a glass of milk , two glasses of milk which one takes singular verb and which one plural?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subject-verb-agreement, subjects, uncountable-nouns

milk is uncountable but when uncountable nouns is placed in a countable container then it becomes countable . So , when i use a glass of milk it becomes countable but either it is singular or not please help me. Also help me either two glasses of milk is singular or plural countable and which verb it will take .

Comment: One glass of milk is good; two are better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject you are asking about is "glass" versus "glasses".  "of milk" is just a prepositional phrase.

> A glass is here.
>
> Two glasses are here.

Adding in prepositional phrases doesn't change the verb, because they're not the subject.

> A glass of milk is here.
>
> Two glasses of warm milk are here.

Answer (score 0):

I drank a glass of milk.

I drank two glasses of milk.

Both are correct.

Comment: i ask if a glass of water used as a subject what will it take as verb and in case of  two glasses of milk

Comment: Many verbs can be used boil, agitate, simmer ...